# MongoDB - Aggregate by distinct field then count per day

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

I have a mongodb database that collects device data.
Example document is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c125a185dea1b0252c5352"),
    "time" : ISODate("2018-12-13T15:09:42.536Z"),
    "mac" : "10:06:21:3e:0a:ff",
}
```

The goal would be to count the unique mac values per day, from the first document in the db to the last document in the db.

I've been playing around and came to the conclusion that I would need to have multiple groups as well as projects during my aggregations.

This is what I tried - not sure if it's in the right direction or not or just completely messed up.

```
   pipeline = [
        {"$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "mac": 1,
            "day": {
                "$dayOfMonth":"$time"
            },
            "month": {
                "$month":"$time"
            },
            "year": {
                "$year":"$time"
            }
        }
        },
        {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "mac": 1,
            "time": {
                "$concat": [{
                    "$substr":["$year", 0, 4]
                },
                "-", {
                    "$substr": ["$month", 0, 2]

                },
                "-",
                {
                    "$substr":["$day", 0, 2]
                }]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "time": "$time",
                    "mac": "$mac"
                }
            },
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.time",
                "count":{"$sum": 1},
            }
        }
    ]

    data = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True))
```

The output now doesn't look like it did any aggregation,

```
[{"_id": null, "count": 751050}]
```

I'm using Pymongo as my driver and using Mongodb 4.

Ideally it should just show the date and count (eg { "_id" : "2018-12-13", "count" : 2 }.

I would love some feedback and advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you had the right idea, you just had the second $group syntactically in the wrong place - you have it imbedded inside first $group when it should be the next stage.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to do this with a single $group stage (and second stage to transform output to desired format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to minimize the number of stages, and especially to avoid unnecessary $group stages.  So I would do it with the following pipeline:

```
pipeline = [ 
  { '$group' : {
      '_id': { '$dateToString': { 'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': "$time" } },
      'macs':{ '$addToSet': '$mac' }
   } },
   {$addFields:{ 'macs':{'$size':'$macs'}}}
]
```

Comment: Wow, This is a lot more efficient than adding 2 group stages

Answer (score 1):

There's an operator called "$dateToString", which would solve most of your problems.

Edit: Didn't read the question carefully, @Asya Kamsky, thank you for pointing out. Here' the new answer.

```
  pipeline = [
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "date": {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
            date: "$time"
          }
        },
        "mac": "$mac"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.date",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: that's wrong - it doesn't give you the number of unique devices per day, it gives you the total number of devices per day counting the same ones multiple times.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky My bad for not reading the question carefully, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
                {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "mac": 1,
                "time": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$time", "timezone": "Africa/Johannesburg"}}
            },
        },

        {
            "$group": {
                "_id":{
                "time": "$time",
                "mac": "$mac",
            }}},{
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.time",
                "count":{"$sum": 1}
            }},
         {"$sort": SON([("_id", -1)])}

]
```

Does exactly what it should do. 
Thanks. :)

Comment: This works correctly however, there is no need to have a $project stage, the expression to calculate time can be used directly in the $group stage.